# How do you purchase a premium car in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

At which level is it possible to purchase premium cars, and how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purchase premium cars "online" using your in-game phone, browse those Vehicle websites.

Well, I assume you don't have much money at low levels, but if you do, you can purchase it at Level 1.